# Popup not attached to marker in Nuxt3

Tags: popup, mapbox, nuxt3

**Structure**

- Nuxt version: "nuxt": "^3.2.0"
- Mapbox dependencie version : "vue-mapbox-ts": "^0.9.7"
- Mapbox devDependencie version : "@types/mapbox-gl": "^2.7.10"

**Context**

I'm trying to attach my popup to marker mapbox.

**Use**

I'm checking the doc to test config but they are points that I don't understand. There is my code. Is similar to the doc. I just change with my data:

```
<mapbox-map :access-token="MAPBOX_ACCESS_TOKEN" :zoom="13" :center="location">
  <mapbox-marker :lng-lat="location" color="#0c1533">
    <mapbox-popup>
      <div>I am the content of an attached Popup</div>
    </mapbox-popup>
  </mapbox-marker>
</mapbox-map>
```

As you can see on screenshot, my mapbox is correctly initiate. We have the correct position of marker but the the popup is not attached to the marker. I miss something ?
[image]

Otherwise, in the doc it is mentioned `new mapboxgl`
but ts cannot find it. What is it and should I get it or do I just not need it?

Thank you for all answers could be help me !

[ref doc](https://gitlab.com/relief-melone/vue-mapbox-ts)